# Does "cherché" mean far-fetched?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

This sentence comes from [Proust](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Proust_-_Du_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_chez_Swann.djvu/133):

> C’est un charmant esprit, si particulier, il a une façon à lui de dire
> les choses un peu cherchée, mais si agréable.

Moncrieff translates it as 'far-fetched' and while I'm inclined to believe him I can't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: Though it depends a lot on the broader context, I'm not sure "imaginé", "inventé" is the best translation here. Better than the infinitive, you can take a look at the adjective tab on the same cnrtl page.

Comment: It seems you overlooked the entry that  really concerns you: [this one](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cherch%C3%A9/1). To make a direct link to  one of the entries that are shown framed at the top of the page, add a right slash to the url and then the number "K-1", where K is the order of appearance of the given frame in the line ("/0" does work, but of course, it is not needed).

Comment: cool, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Far-fetched is not a bad translation, but IMO is missing the idea that *cherché* is also the opposite of "natural" - i.e. calculated, slightly affected or pedantic.

Since

> recherché

is the modern version of *cherché* and exists in English, you could also use that. Merriam Webster [suggests](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recherche) "excessively refined" as a definition of it.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cherch%C3%A9/1 (adjective tab)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think *far fetched* to be an appropriate translation here. For my native French speaker sense, *cherché* is used here as *recherché* and means using wordings that are perfectly correct but uncommon in current language level. For example using *passé simple* or *subjonctif imparfait* conjugation when speaking would be said *recherché*.

On the other hand (but I am not a native English speaker...) far fetched is used for almost inapproriate arguments.

That being said I am not proficient enough in English language to propose a better translation...

Comment: Well, does 'cherché' in French in 1913 have mostly the same meaning as 'recherché' in English today?  I've only seen the word used negatively but it's only midly negative and as far as I know I've only seen the 'pedantic' usage in English.

Comment: Unsure of the meaning of *recherché* in English. But in French it is close to  *pédant* (pedantic in English) but less negative.

Comment: yea, that's basically what it is in English.  Since it's such a rare word I think sometimes people get it wrong.